# a program with the pyscreenshot library cannot be played without idle

Tags: python

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

image = ImageGrab.grab()
image.save('screen.png')
input()
```

The program is started only with IDLE, nothing happens when you try to start the program by double-clicking, What could be the problem?

I tried a lot of options for solving this problem, nothing came out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be multiple Python versions/environments installed on your system, where in IDLE you are in the "correct" environment, while the environment invoked via double-clicking is the wrong one.

You could check that by placing the first three statements into a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) block to see any error messages popping up:

```py
try:
    import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

    image = ImageGrab.grab()
except Exception as exc:
    print("An error has occured:", str(exc))
input()
```

Without this try/except, the error traceback would only be displayed shortly before closing the window. With the try/except, the error message gets displayed and the program halts correctly at `input()`.

I guess that the error will be `An error has occured: No module named 'pyscreenshot'`, which would illustrate the "wrong" environment. You should then try to fix you python shortcut by linking it to the correct environment, i.e. the same you are using in the IDLE.